# QTableView нельзя скопировать всю строку

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Здравствуйте. Есть QTableView. [Вот](https://i.imgur.com/q0Z3E6l.png). Хочу скопировать из него всю строку целиком, но копируется только значение, с которого начинал выделять. Если поставить selectionBehavior на строку, то копируется последнее значение строки.

Еще попробовал делать единую строку и помещать ее в clipboard - в итоге помещается.
В общем как мне получить всю строку из QTableView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перевожу [ответ отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1230530):

Чтобы на самом деле захватить выделение, используйте `QItemSelectionModel` для получения списка индексов. Допустим что есть указатель `view` типа `QTableView*`, получить выборку можно так:

```
QAbstractItemModel * model = view->model();
QItemSelectionModel * selection = view->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList indexes = selection->selectedIndexes();
```

Затем пройдитесь по списку индексов, вызывая `model->data(index)` для каждого индекса. Сконвертируйте данные в строку, если это ещё не строка, и сложите все строки вместе. Затем используйте `QClipboard.setText`, чтобы поместить текст в клипбоард. Замечу, что для Excel и Calc каждый столбец должен быть отделён от следующего символом табуляции (`"\t"`), и каждая строка отделена символом перевода строки (`"\n"`).  Вам нужно смотреть по индексу, когда происходит переход на следующую строку.

```
QString selected_text;
// You need a pair of indexes to find the row changes
QModelIndex previous = indexes.first();
indexes.removeFirst();
foreach(current, indexes)
{
    QVariant data = model->data(current);
    QString text = data.toString();
    // At this point `text` contains the text in one cell 
    selected_text.append(text);
    // If you are at the start of the row the row number of the previous index
    // isn't the same.  Text is followed by a row separator, which is a newline.
    if (current.row() != previous.row())
    {
        selected_text.append('\n');
    }
    // Otherwise it's the same row, so append a column separator, which is a tab.
    else
    {
        selected_text.append('\t');
    }
    previous = current;
}
QApplication.clipboard().setText(selected_text);
```

**NB:** Этот код я не проверял, но аналогичный для PyQt работает.

Comment: да, я клипбоард потом переправил, он заработал. 
Спасибо что пост нашли.  
А про само копирование с таблицы (в плане даже без настройки слотов) ничего нет?